# PostgreSQL - Readonly "SuperUser"

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I am searching for a solution how to create a postgres role, which can connect to all databases(also those being created after the role).

Thats normally something a superuser can do, but in my case, this user should have read-only access only to specific tables.

Is this possible?

Or do I have to update the role everytime I add a new database? Eventhough the table names ar always the same.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PUBLIC can [connect to PostgreSQL databases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) by default.

> PostgreSQL grants default privileges on some types of objects to
>   PUBLIC. No privileges are granted to PUBLIC by default on tables,
>   columns, schemas or tablespaces. For other types, the default
>   privileges granted to PUBLIC are as follows: CONNECT and CREATE TEMP
>   TABLE for databases; EXECUTE privilege for functions; and USAGE
>   privilege for languages.

If you're using pgAdminIII, and you select a database in the object browser, you'll see this in the SQL pane.

```
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE sandbox TO public;
```

You can [change default privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) on some kinds of database objects using `alter default privileges`. This doesn't affect existing database objects. Grant privileges on existing objects the usual way.

`alter default privileges` is a "per database" statement; you can't alter default privileges for databases that haven't yet been created.

You *can* grant privileges for tables that exist. You *can* alter *default* privileges for all tables that don't yet exist. But you *can't* alter default privileges for tables having specific names that don't yet exist.

You might be able to set up suitable privileges and defaults on objects in [the template database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html). Then every database you create will include those objects, privileges, and defaults.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now what I wanted. But ok, this way I have to update the user everytime a new DB is created.

Comment: Depends on who the user is, and on what you can put in the template database.